# amCharts - missing columns in Bar/Column graphs

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amCharts version 1.1 to create column/bar graphs. The issue occurs when I render a graph that has more than one column (see images below, hover for more info in tooltip)
    [image: figure 1]
    [image: figure 2]
    [image: figure 3]

Now how do I make sure that the chart does not miss the bars? This works perfectly in the line graph (shows all 9 data points) so why is it missing only here?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a property startOnAxis set to true (default is false). Try setting it to false or remove this property at all.

Comment: Yes, that worked.

        categoryAxis.startOnAxis = false;